# Pandas Identify row numbers in lists that has False present in data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this,

```
ColA Result_ColA ColB Result_ColB Result_ColC
1     True        1    True        True
2     False       2    True        False
3     True        3    True        False
```

I want to identify the row numbers inside a list in python, which has a value False present in any of the Result_ columns.

For the given dataframe, the false list will have row number [2 and 3] present in it. considering the row numbers starting from 1.

Type Error Tracebacks :

```
ReqRows = np.arange(1, len(Out_df)+ 1)[Out_df.eq(False).any(axis=1).values].tolist()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-92-497c7b225e2a>", line 1, in <module>
    ReqRows = np.arange(1, len(Out_df)+ 1)[Out_df.eq(False).any(axis=1).values].tolist()

  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 1279, in f
    return self._combine_const(other, na_op)

  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3625, in _combine_const
    raise_on_error=raise_on_error)

  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3162, in eval
    return self.apply('eval', **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 3056, in apply
    applied = getattr(b, f)(**kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 1115, in eval
    transf(values), other)

  File "C:\Users\aaa\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 2247, in _try_coerce_args
    raise TypeError

TypeError
```

Comment: The title of your question sounds like a news item :D add a colon or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create helper 1d array by length of DataFrame starting by `1` and filter it bay all rows contains at least one `False`:

```
a = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)[df.eq(False).any(axis=1).values].tolist()
print (a)
[2, 3]
```

You can also get only boolean columns first by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html):

```
arr = (df.select_dtypes(include=[bool])).eq(False).any(axis=1).values
a = np.arange(1, len(df) + 1)[arr].tolist()
```

Comment: It says include and exclude must both be non string.

Comment: @Sid29 - What about this solution?

Comment: The new solution gives me a Type Error - Could be the version of python..

Comment: @Sid29 - yes, it is possible, I try a bit change answer with `.values` for convert `Series` to `1d` array.

Comment: @jezrael works for me, both our solutions. Might be something else, we need traceback.. :)

Comment: A Type Error again.

Comment: @Sid29 - Can you test if working `(df.select_dtypes(include=[bool]))` ?

Comment: Will do. Tracebacks added to the question now. Thanks.

Comment: (df.select_dtypes(include=[bool])) works for me and gives all the result columns.

Comment: @Sid29 - Super, so check last paragraph of answer, it should working nice.

Comment: Yes, the OR Solution works for me. Thank you so much.

Comment: @jezrael would like to know what happened there. For learning purposes. :)

Comment: @anky_91 - I think old version of pandas - so you need compare only boolean columns.

Comment: @jezrael ok, so no need to worry then. :p

Comment: @anky_91 - yes, in oldier version solution is not easy answering, because not easy verify solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Also :

```
list(df.loc[(df==False).any(axis=1)].index+1)
#[2, 3]
```

Comment: It gives me a Type Error.

Comment: @Sid29 error saying what? did you try on the dataframe in the question? works fine for me. :)

Comment: I did and it says - raise TypeError

Comment: @Sid29 can you please ad the traceback in the post so we can understand why. Thanks